# python file parsing next() function

Tags: python

I've got some functions to parse text files with program data output. While parsing, obviously, I look for some patterns in text that mark data. But if the needed line is not marked anyhow and may be defined only in a way like 'the third line from the line, starting with 'data' keyword' I use next() function to count those lines (e.g. if i need to count down three lines there will be three line = next(fo) statements. See sample function for example:

```
def get_length(fn):
    with open(fn, 'r') as inp:
        for line in inp:
            if line.strip().startswith('HOMOGENEIZED CROSS SECTIONS FOR CELL'):
                line = next(inp)
                line = next(inp)
                line = next(inp)
                sigtr = float(line.split()[9])
                siga = float(line.split()[6])
    length = 1.0/(3.0*sigtr*siga)
    return length
```

This counting lines with next() seems pretty dumb to me. Maybe, there's some more elegant and pythonic way to implement such 'line counting'?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
def get_length(fn):
    with open(fn, 'r') as inp:
        x = None
        for n, line in enumerate(inp):
            if x is None and line.strip().startswith('HOMOGENEIZED CROSS SECTIONS FOR CELL'):
                x = n + 3
            elif x == n:
                sigtr = float(line.split()[9])
                siga = float(line.split()[6])
                x = None
    length = 1.0/(3.0*sigtr*siga)
    return length
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you *could* write a generic iterable-consuming function which consumes `n` units of a given generator/iterator. Something like:

```
def consume_and_ignore(gen, n):
    for _ in itertools.repeat(None, n):
        next(gen)


def get_length(fn):
    with open(fn, 'r') as inp:
        for line in inp:
            if line.strip().startswith('HOMOGENEIZED CROSS SECTIONS FOR CELL'):
                consume_and_ignore(inp, 2)
                line = next(inp)
                sigtr = float(line.split()[9])
                siga = float(line.split()[6])
    length = 1.0/(3.0*sigtr*siga)
    return length
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def get_length(fn):

with open(fn, 'r') as inp:

    li = inp.readlines()
    i = 0
    while(i<len(li)):
        if li[i].strip().startswith('HOMOGENEIZED CROSS SECTIONS FOR CELL'):         i = i+3
            sigtr = float(li[i].split()[9])
            siga = float(li[i].split()[6])
length = 1.0/(3.0*sigtr*siga)
return length
```

try this